# How can I remove the title of a SettingsPanel with SettingsPanelNoMenu in Kivy?

Tags: python, settings, customization, kivy

I'd like to customize the SettingsPanelNoMenu but I haven't found where and how to change it.

The change is pretty small so I think to make an own Interface would be too complicated and it should be easier to do.

The settings page is inside a TabbedPanel and you can find the source code here:
https://gist.github.com/AWolf81/3f122de3ef559eaec202

And here is the thing I'd like to change. I want to remove the title (marked with red circle) of the SettingsPanel because it's already highlighted in the TabbedPanel:

[image: Screenshot of DemoApp]

What's the easiest way to remove that title?

Setting the title to an empty string would be one option but then the label of the title is still there and the gap between the tab name and the first setting would be too large.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found a solution and it's pretty easy.

Just override the style of SettingsPanel in your KV file/string. I've tried this before but I missed to add the minus sign to remove the original styling. It's important here because otherwise the label of the base style will be drawn.

I've added these lines to my KV string and then it works as expected:

```
<-SettingsPanel>:
    spacing: 5
    padding: 5
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
```

I've also updated the Gist of this demo.

Here is how it looks now:

[image: Settings in TabbedPanel fixed]